# Assign value to checkbox based on order it is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to assign a value of 5 if a checkbox is clicked first and a value of 2 for the second checkbox that is selected. The form is meant to have a primary and secondary selection based on the order that the box is checked. What I have below doesn't seem to work.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form" value="2" name="option-1">
<input type="checkbox" class="form" value="2" name="option-2">

<script type="text/javascript">
var firstClick = true;

  $('input.form').click(function() {

       if(firstClick){
           firstClick = 5;
  });
</script>
```

Update:
I tried Samuel's method but the form is still returning a value of 2 for each item.

Comment: Please share the sample code in which you are working on

Comment: Can we see some code please? If you don't have any, it's better to atleast give it a try. If you get stuck, then we are here for you.

Comment: Yes Samuel, I would like the first one clicked to set the value to 5 and the second box selected to set the value to 2. Thanks for the help. I will try it out.

Comment: That's a statement, not a question. It seems that readers are expected to infer that it doesn't do what you want in some unspecified way, and to figure out what that is, before they can even start to examine what's the cause. How about explaining what results you're getting and how they differ from the intended results?

Comment: *"I am trying to assign a value of 5 if a checkbox is clicked first and a value of 2 for the second checkbox that is selected"*  - I'm getting confused. Do you want to set the value to `5` if something is clicked for the first time, and `2` from next time onwards, or do you want to set `5` for the first checkbox and `2` for second checkbox whenever they are selected..?

Comment: TJ, The latter. There will be six options total but the user will only be able to select a Primary (the first click) and a Secondary (the second click) option for their answer. Noy's response worked for what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you forgot to change the flag
2. you need to set the val in the checkbox

Modified code:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form" value="2" name="option-1">
<input type="checkbox" class="form" value="2" name="option-2">

<script type="text/javascript">
var firstClick = true;

  $('input.form[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
       if(firstClick) {
           $(this).val(5);
           firstClick = false;
       }
  });
</script>
```